# relation set theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, relations

I was reading about relation and function https://www.purplemath.com/modules/fcns.htm

And I was not able to understand this phrase in it where it says "So then this is not a function. Heck, **it ain't even a relation!**"

I could definitely understand why it isn't a function but couldn't understand why it isn't a relation either. I believe there is no rule for a relation to be a relation. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific where the question is located on that article. It would speed things up

Comment: There is an element in the domain : $16$ which has no "related" element in the range. An object $x$ is in $\text {Dom}(R)$ iff there is an element $y$ such that $(x,y) \in R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a function (as the element 16 of the domain doesn't have an image), but I don't agree with the claim that it is not a relation. A relation between two sets $A$ and $B$ is usually defined just as a subset of $A\times B$.

And the image in your link describes such a subset, namely $$\{(-3,-6),(-2,-1),(-1,0),(0,3),(1,15)\} \subseteq A\times B$$ with $A = \{-3,-2,-1,0,1,16\}$ and $B = \{-6,-1,0,3,15\}$. That is a relation.

Comment: I agree with azimut. Sometimes relations for which every element of the domain has at least one corresponding element of the codomain are called "total".